# SSIS project failure due to ODBC error after upgrade to SQL Server 2019

Tags: mysql, ssis, odbc, visual-studio-2019

We are in the process of upgrading SQL Server from 2012 to 2019. One SSIS project is failing after the upgrade, it was working perfectly before. One SSIS package in this project has a data flow task which loads data from MySQL database and inserts into Microsoft SQL Server. This data flow task is inside a for loop and loads 1 million rows in each loop.

The first loop executes successfully and inserts the correct data into destination. But the problem occurs in the second loop. The second loops fails because of below mentioned errors:

> Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "ODBC Source.Outputs[ODBC Source Output]" failed because error code 0xC020F450 occurred, and the error row disposition on "ODBC Source" specifies failure on error.

> SQLSTATE: HY010, Message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Function sequence error;

The SQL query used in the second loop has no issues and gives correct results when executed on database directly. But the data output from the SSIS ODBC source in the second loop has empty values in all the columns. I changed the batch size from 1 million rows to  1000 rows, the second loop still failed with the same error. And if the project is executed again with same data range that is used in second loop (which was failed previously), it runs successfully (but again the next second loop fails). So, it seems the error is not because of some data type mismatch from source.

I tried out different things mentioned below but nothing helped:

- Downgrading the MySQL ODBC driver to the version which was used in SQL Server 2012
- Recreating the ODBC connection manager in SSIS project
- Recreating the Data flow task
- Installing the latest version of SQL Server Integration Services Projects in VS 2019.

Comment: "Downgrading the MySQL ODBC driver to older version" Does this mean the exact, point level release, as the 2012 solution's or just an earlier version? Based on your description, it feels like the error is going to be with the driver itself, like it's partially closed the connection so it does not think it's closed but when it attempts to communicate, it blows up. You could try Right Click on the MySQL Connection Manager and change the `RetainSameConnection`  property from False to `True`

Comment: Thanks @billinkc for you reply, the MySQL ODBC driver was downgraded to the version which was working for SQL Server 2012. I have edited my question. I set the RetainSameConnection property to True, but still it is failing with the same error.